# LDAP Group Sync with Apache ranger not working

Tags: security, ldap, hadoop2

I have installed and configured `OpenLDAP` server on `Hortonworks HDP 2.5` sandbox.
As per the HDP 2.5 documentation, I have configured Apache Ranger to get synced with LDAP user and groups. I am able to sync user created in LDAP with ranger but groups are not getting sync.
I am doing this syncing so that group level authorization policies can be created in Hadoop.

My LDAP configuration is as follows:

```
ldapUrl: ldap://sandbox.hortonworks.com:389,  
ldapBindDn: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com,  
ldapBindPassword: ***** ,  
ldapAuthenticationMechanism: simple,  
searchBase: ou=People,dc=example,dc=com,  
userSearchBase: [ou=People,dc=example,dc=com],  
userSearchScope: 2,  
userObjectClass: top,  
userSearchFilter: cn=*,  
extendedUserSearchFilter: (&(objectclass=top)(cn=*)),  
userNameAttribute: uid,  
userSearchAttributes: [uid],  
userGroupNameAttributeSet: null,  
pagedResultsEnabled: true,  
pagedResultsSize: 500,  
groupSearchEnabled: true,  
groupSearchBase: [ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com],  
groupSearchScope: 2,  
groupObjectClass: posixGroup,  
groupSearchFilter: cn=*,  
extendedGroupSearchFilter: (&(objectclass=posixGroup)(cn=*)(|(member={0})(member={1}))),  
extendedAllGroupsSearchFilter: (&(objectclass=posixGroup)(cn=*)),  
groupMemberAttributeName: member,  
groupNameAttribute: cn, 
groupSearchAttributes: [member, cn],  
groupUserMapSyncEnabled: true, 
groupSearchFirstEnabled: false, 
userSearchEnabled: false,  
ldapReferral: ignore
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Formatting is now more clear, styling makes it easier to read